# Layout.xml Action Calling Block Class Method

Tags: magento-enterprise, layout, blocks, ee-1.13

I was working on adding the ability to set a default product list sorting option for just search results, when I noticed that `\app\code\core\Mage\CatalogSearch\Block\Result.php` has the method `setListOrders()`. I couldn't find any PHP code that called this method, but did find this:

**\app\design\frontend\base\default\layout\catalogsearch.xml**

`<action method="setListOrders"/>`

This suggests to me that the method is simply called, without passing any data, at some point before the layout is rendered. Can someone tell me more about how this works, and where this happens in the process of building the page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[It's a dependency injection system via XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13755707/how-are-action-methods-within-magento-layout-xml-files-intended-to-be-used).

When generating/instantiating the layout blocks (usually with `$this->loadLayout()` in a controller), Mage will parse the computed layout XML, calling `Mage_Core_Model_Layout::generateBlocks` for every `block` node, in a recursive manner.

Then, among other things, it searches for `action` nodes in the current `block` node. When it finds one, it passes the `action` node to `Mage_Core_Model_Layout::_generateAction`, which calls [call_user_func_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) for you, with the method you specified in the `method` node attribute (and optional arguments).

It looks like this:
`call_user_func_array(array([Mage_CatalogSearch_Block_Result object], 'setListOrders'), array());`

Answer (score 1):

You can visit this [document](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-4-magento-layouts-blocks-and-templates) to check how it works. quick summary: when you loadLayout it will look for all tag in xml, e.g.: ,,. so when Magento see  it would call public PHP methods of the block classes. and output to html when you call renderLayout.

you can dump layout data to see what blocks you load by using getLayout().